# One feature - several units

Tags: feature-engineering, feature-construction, features

I have a dataframe where one of the features is the Mileage expressed in some cases in $\frac{km}{l}$, while in others is expressed in $\frac{km}{kg}$, according to the combustion type of the car (so I can't just convert some and have all expressed in the same unit because that'd make no sense).

I think it makes no sense to just ignore this and treat all numbers equally. The first approach I can think of consists of creating two separate columns for each case, in which case for each register in the dataset, one column will have a number while the other will be empty. I could then fill nans with the average value of the column, thinking of it as 'the most neutral value it could get'.

Another option I can think of consists of saving all the values in the same column, and have another column to indicate the type of units used in each case, e.g. $\frac{km}{l}$ maps to $1$; $\frac{km}{kg}$ maps to $0$.

I'm not convinced by any of the two approaches, but at the same time can't think of anything better. If anyone can help me think of a better approach to deal in this cases, I'd be very thankful.

Edit1:

Here are the types of fuel and their respective units.

```
CNG: ['km/kg']
Diesel: ['kmpl']
Petrol: ['kmpl']
LPG: ['km/kg']
Electric: [nan]
```

Although it would be possible to convert cng kg to l, it would be a different meaning in each case.

One thing I thought of was to express this information in terms of price per km... Until now, it seems the most reasonable thing to do.

Comment: If you know which type of cars have $\frac{km}{kg}$ and which $\frac{km}{l}$, what prevents you from conversion? (Is that **l** liter?) If so, I think for different liquids you can convert kg to l (These are almost equal)

Comment: Yes, l is for liters. I now edited the question addressing your approach. Thanks for your time!

Comment: What is meant by kmpl?  I think you'll need to convert all to same units.  Also, what do you mean, "it would be a different meaning in each case."?

Comment: It appears to me that you can find a common unit of measure.  Ultimately what you have is a length / a volume of energy

Comment: kmpl is kilometers per liter. What I mean by _it would be a different meaning in each case_ is that in the case that I convert all to the same units, it's not necessary that similar numbers would indicate similar fuel efficiency.